# Data reduction via IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am trying to do some data reduction in my Google Sheets by using the following IMPORTRANGE formula:

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/a/ap.averydennison.com/spreadsheets/d/1xz1lXY-w5Ii_aWqVAhHgRCmeoes9ltSUtibE4kzhMHA/edit#gid=2051232966","SF_Flex_Rel!a:l"), 
 "select * where Col1 = '"&text(B1,"###")&"'",1)
```

The 'source' sheet has a whole lot of sales data records. What I am trying to do in the new sheet via this formula is only bring in the sales records from the source sheet that match the customer number specified in cell B1.

It seems to work OK if I limit the IMPORTRANGE to only query about 10,000 rows. Once I go over around 20,000 rows the screen will briefly flash up the records, then a small progress bar shows in the top right corner of the sheet and the records disappear. The cell with the formula just shows `#ERROR!` with no other comments to tell me why.

Is there something wrong with my formula syntax?

Is there a better way to achieve this data reduction?

Is there some undocumented data limitation on IMPORTRANGE function (I am using 'new' Google Sheets)?

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem (4 columns, it stops at around 50,000 rows - full formula works only during 3 seconds when I open the ss) if I reduce the columns size to "Sheet1!A:B" (instead of "Sheet1!A:D") it works. If I change the "select *" with "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4" I have the following error: "'Error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMNA" ! One thing that I have noticed is that the column D contains many time the same numbers (from 1 to 200). I have tried to move the D  column in C and I have the same error. So it is possibly a Google bug ?

Answer (score 0):

try like my example :

```
  =QUERY(                                                // data
              IMPORTRANGE(
                "Spreadsheet Key",    // spreadsheet key 
                "DATA!A:C"                                         // datarange
              ), 
              "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2=" & "'" & B2 & "'"           // query
            )
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I tried your suggestion. It looks like the main difference is that you have removed the text function. When I initially made the change the error changed to "#N/A - Query completed with an empty output". When I refresh the browser it briefly shows the column headings from the source sheet and then reverts to "#REF! - Error circular dependency detected" - which is odd as I have not changed any actual cell references.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This answer helped me find a workaround  : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/RxVUFGWQ2Y4

In my example :

1) In the spreadsheet where the data is I have added a few empty columns (E to H) in order to display 4 columns of data in 5 maximum rows.
=Query(Sheet1!A:D,"select * Where A contains 'KEYWORD' limit 5",1)

2) Then in the other spreadsheet:
=ImportRange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ss_key_here/", "'Sheet1'!E1:H5")

Comment: Thanks for the link to that article. I will try splitting my importrange over groups of columns in the target worksheet and see if that overcomes the limitation.